# vim multiuser editing? 

Tags: vim, multiple-users

With vim, can two users edit the same file at the same time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry no such feature, found this advice:

> The common suggestion is to use a shared "GNU Screen" session:
>
> http://groups.google.com/group/vim_use/browse_thread/thread/f502e7783038d484/c4603374d2e752b2
>
> to do collaborative editing in Vim.  However, it's a bit tricky
>   because it's modal, so if one person changes modes, the other
>   person has to adapt accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

Sorry to dig out this old question but as I bumped on it and found an answer here it is:

Have a try with
https://github.com/FredKSchott/CoVim

EDIT: this project is now archived on Github, last change was made on 2017

Comment: CoVim plugin need twisted as dependency `pip install twisted`

Comment: Seems to be dead and rotting now.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any vim plugins for collaborative editing, but have a look at [gobby](http://gobby.0x539.de/trac/).

Comment: I wonder if gobby has vim key bindings though.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so, because Vim creates a swap file any time you open a file. This swap file helps if you want to recover after some sort of an error. When the second user opens the file, his or her Vim will see the swap file and get an error and the options to ignore, delete, recover, etc. I don't think that both users would be able to simultaneously edit this file.

I think the best way to have both users work on the same file is to use a version control system. I like mercurial (good tutorial [here](http://hginit.com/index.html)), but subversion and git are the classics.

Comment: Good suggestion about using version control.  That solves so many problems in one fell swoop.

Comment: the swap file is not the problem. its just not that each user can see what the others are typing :)

Answer (score 2):

i know it's dirty too but you may use `screen` for the first terminal then `screen -x` on the second one and so on when logged into a terminal with the same user from somewhere else

Answer (score 2):

[vim-multiuser](https://github.com/emgram769/vim-multiuser) looks interesting. It actually allows users to be in different modes at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

There's a [Multiplayer](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=5555) vim plugin leveraging ssh and swap files to do the job. Users have individual settings, registers and stuff while allowing them to look into each others' editing contexts.

Also [Floobits](https://floobits.com/) has a [plugin for neovim](https://github.com/Floobits/floobits-neovim).

Answer (score 0):

Somebody has mentioned something similar on [Hackernews](http://news.ycombinator.com/). You might want to check it out:

http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=720764

You might also want to take a look at [DocSynch](http://docsynch.sourceforge.net/) (its peresently available only for JEd, a VIM plugin is supposedly still in development). One dirty hack would be to sync your files over a file storage service like [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com).